# Objects falling in android

Tags: android, android-animation

- Just now I came accross this animation in an **Android App**. I was wondering which kind animation is this. Tell me name of this animation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague but i will try to answer it. It looks like confetti and it depends on the developer how he has created it. But you can look [here](https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=confetti&category=animations&animations-page=1) for this kind of animations . Lottie is pretty smooth than our regular animations. Try it once. All the best.